# Error converting Java code into Kotlin code

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following statement in Java

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
};
```

and I tried to convert into Kotlin code and I have

```
private var mBroadcastReceiver:BroadcastReceiver = 
    object:BroadcastReceiver(){
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver)
            stopSelf()
        }
    }
```

but I have the next error in

```
unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver)
```

> Variable mBroadcastReceiver must be initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing `this` instead of the `mBroadcastReceiver` into the function:

`unregisterReceiver(this)`

Comment: It work's! i'm feel like a dummy, I forgot it and I use it instead of this (facepalm)